# Не могу понять что делает код C++

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, математика

Я должен разобрать код, оптимизировать его и переделать на С#. Оптимизация и перевод в С# мне даётся относительно легко, но вот понять что он делает я не могу. Код прикрепляю:

````
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int j = 0, i, d = 1, k, count = 0, c, b[100], m, n, l, z;
  cout << "Enter the positive number: ";
  cin >> c;
  cout << "Enter the positive number: ";
  cin >> m;
  for (i = c + 1; i < 100000; i++)
  {
    l = i;
    while (l % 10 != 0 || l - (l % 10) != 0)
    {
      d = l % 10;
      l /= 10;
      b[j] = d;
      j++;
    }
    for (n = 0; n < j; n++)
    {
      if (b[n] == 7)
        count++;
    }
    if (count == m)
    {
      cout << "-------------- Result: " << i;
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      count = 0;
      for (int n = 0; n < j; n++)
      {
        b[n] = 0;
      }
      j = 0;
    }
  }
  return 0;
} ```
````

Comment: Для чисел от с+1  и до 99999 вывести первое число, в котором будет m семерок? *"По-моему, так" (с) Пух* Только сделано, как мне кажется, немного через, гм...

Comment: То что сделано убого я и так вижу, например переменные k и z вообще не используются, но для этого и буду делать оптимизацию. Большое спасибо

Comment: Точно! Сделано через «универсальный интерфейс». С ошибкой в цикле разбора на цифры. Мне кажется проще перевести число в строку, и просто посчитать количество символов `7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, ищем первое число, большее `с` и не превышающее 100000, в десятичной записи которого m семерок.

Ищем через... вобщем, `->(_!_)->`

Перебором я бы делал так:

```
int main()
{
    int c, m;
    cin >> c >> m;
    for(int i = c + 1; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int j = i; j; j/=10)
            if (j%10==7) ++count;
        if (count == m)
        {
            cout << "-------------- Result: " << i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```